Authorship / Derivation of the Yehi Ratzon יְהִי רָצוֹן at the End of the Amidah
In Nusach Ashkenaz we say at the end of each Amidah, a three phrase  Yehi Ratzon for the rebuilding of the Bet HaMikdash (Temple).
Can anyone shed light on the authorship or derivation of this Yehi Ratzon?
The text is:
[1]
יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּ֒פָנֶֽיךָ יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתֵֽינוּ שֶׁיִּבָּנֶה בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ בִּמְהֵרָה בְיָמֵֽינוּ וְתֵן חֶלְקֵֽנוּ בְּתוֹרָתֶֽךָ:
וְשָׁם נַעֲבָדְךָ בְּיִרְאָה כִּימֵי עוֹלָם וּכְשָׁנִים קַדְמוֹנִיּוֹת:  [2]
וְעָרְ֒בָה לַיהוָֹה מִנְחַת יְהוּדָה וִירוּשָׁלָֽםִ כִּימֵי עוֹלָם וּכְשָׁנִים קַדְמוֹנִיּוֹת:  [3]
[1] May it be thy will, O Lord our God, and God of our fathers that the temple be speedily rebuilt in our days, and grant us our portion in thy Law.
[2] And there we will serve you with awe, as in the days of old, and as in ancient years.
[3] Then shall the offering of Judah and Jerusalem be pleasant unto the Lord, as in the days of old, and as in ancient years.
[Translation from (UK) Authorised Daily Prayer Book, Second Edition, 1962].
[3] comes verbatim from Malachi 3:4.
[1] is similar to (but not identical with) this phrase from Pirkei Avot 5:20:
יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶיךָ יְיָ אֱלֹהֵינוּ שֶׁתִּבְנֶה עִירְךָ בִּמְהֵרָה בְיָמֵינוּ וְתֵן חֶלְקֵנוּ בְתוֹרָתֶךָ:
[2] I have not yet found a source for [2].
And in any event what is the source for (1) joining together these three phrases and (2) placing this Yehi Ratzon at the end of each Amidah.
I am aware of this post Yehi ratzon for the rebuilding of the Temple. I do not think mine is a duplicate of the earlier post

#2 is based on psalms 2:11.

@Shababnik in part, yes. Tehillim 2:11 reads עִבְד֣וּ אֶת־יְהֹוָ֣ה בְּיִרְאָ֑ה וְ֜גִ֗ילוּ בִּרְעָדָֽה: so it is potentially the source for נַעֲבָדְךָ בְּיִרְאָה

Still looking for the source for (1) joining together these three phrases and (2) placing this Yehi Ratzon at the end of every Amidah.

The second phrase is also found in ותערב, which is a variant of Retzei that is said in Mussaf on days when Birkat Kohanim is customarily said in the Diaspora (i.e. Yom Tov). According to  Wikipedia, it is possible that ותערב is the original Eretz Yisraeli version of Retzei; this original version thus may be the source of the second phrase.

Welcome to Mi Yodeya @JudahOfChelm. Thank you for your answer. It’s helpful but does not get me much further with And in any event what is the source for joining together these phrases and placing this Yehi Ratzon at the end of each Amidah.
